# ios9 Login with facebook sdk not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios9.3

if the facebook app is already installed it doesn't redirect to facebook app in ios 9.3
I am getting following issue.
 -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb"

Answer (score 1):

refer bellow link , i hope it will help for you , you need to add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in plist

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9